# Ubuntu remote desktop user using a key-based login

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS set up and I have a user account which authenticates using a private key to connect via PuTTY. Is it possible to use remote desktop from windows 7 (xrdp) with key-based login?

Comment: Well, have you tried it out? It might be that no-one has tried that out themselves, but if you try it out and encounter some issues with it, it would make your question more specific and more likely to attract some useful responses.

Comment: I can't see how it can be done without entering a password. Sorry I can't provide more.

Comment: Do you mean "no password" as unauthenticated access, or as authenticating with a key instead of a password?

Comment: using a public private key.

Comment: After some more digging, I think the answer to your question is "no". I've thus deleted my answer, the RSA keys in question are not for user authentication purposes.

Comment: What you could do if security is the main concern behind your question, is to tunnel RDP over SSH connection (SSH using PKI authentication), and then use regular password authentication for the RDP session. As far as I know, authenticating RDP with only keys is not something that is possible out-of-the-box on Windows, either (at least easily, and without 3rd party software).